# Python csv Merge several column to one cell

Tags: python, csv

How can I merge the several columns into one cell?
How can I convert a CSV file , that includes 1 by X cells where 1 is the row count and X is the column count unkown by the user,into a new CSV file including one single cell to combine all data from the original CSV file?

Right now://One row, four columns  #####In fact, it will be variable number of columns as the data is extracted from a log file#############

```
1 A   B  C   D
```

My purposes:  //One row, one colum

```
1 A
  B
  C
  D
```

The index of the row may not be always be 1 as I have many similar rows like that.

please refer to the original file and the expected new file at the following URL for details
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cX0o86nbLAV5Foj5avCK6E2oAvExzt5t

```
161.csv is the file at the present
161-final.csv is what I want...
```

The count of rows will not be changed. However, the count of columns is a variable as the data is extracted from a log file. In the end, I only need each row has only one column.

I am just a fresh man with pandas. Will it be a way that I calculate the count of columns and then merge it into one cell?

Very appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you already set up the code to open the file, open a second file to write to and set up to iterate through it?

Comment: Yes. I already had a function which concate two csv df1,df2 into df3. df1 is a defined format csv. df2 is generated from filtering some key lines from my log file. However, as the df2 is extrated from a log file, it may have variable columns on it. I  can't simply concat it with read_csv(dfx) and pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1) as it may have c errors. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b']])
print(df)
df1 = np.empty(df.shape[0], dtype=object)
df1[:] = df.values.tolist()

print(df1)
```

output:

```
0  1  2  3
0  a  a  a  a
1  b  b  b  b
[list(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']) list(['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but you can manage to put the content of one row in a single column with `pd.groupby()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape(1, 4))
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: x.values.ravel())
df = df.to_frame('unique_col') # If needed
```

Output :

```
     unique_col
0  [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Not sure this is possible to have the output not in a list as you mentioned it in your example.

Comment: Sorry I will provide more details. The csv was extracted from a log file with filtering some key lines. Therefore, it may have different coloumns. Each columns may have a sentence like:"Thu Mar 22 13:21:40 2018-WA-ROUTER-0: OSPF: Can't connect to SNMP agent with SMUX". How can I assign it to a dataframe and use groupby?dataframe and use groupby?

Answer (score 0):

I used a "stupid" way to do that. It is the "pd.read_table(file)" do the magic.

```
def CsvMerge(file1, file2,output):
##It is for preparation of the getFormated()
##Merge the "Format.csv" and the "text.csv.csv
  df1=pd.read_csv(file1)
###This is for merging the columns to one column
###It can also avoid an csv error
  df2=pd.read_table(file2)
  df3=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
  print(df3)
  with open(output,'w+',encoding="utf-8") as f:
      df3.to_csv(f,index=False)
  f.close()
```